# Using Eclipse's Console font

Tags: java, eclipse, console

I am trying to rebuild the Eclipse console in a JFrame.

Now I can't seem to find a way to use Eclipse's Console Font.

I know it's called `CVS Console Font` but I have no idea how to 'reach' it.

E.g.:

```
Font consoleFont = new Font(?????);
textArea.setFont(consoleFont);
```

Does anybody know how I can load this font?

### Update: Resolved

I think this font is called `Consolas`. Wikipedia says [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consolas) about it.

This font is also selectable as you can see from Eclipse font selector:

[image]

Hence I think I found the font I was looking for.

Comment: http://www.codemiles.com/java-examples/fonts-in-java-t2831.html - Should be able to help you. You should be able to list all fonts available. Also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/fonts.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy:

```
org.eclipse.jface.resource.JFaceResources.getFontRegistry().get("pref_console_font");
```

That will return a Font object which is Eclipse's Console Font.

But I want to remind you that: The CSV plugin is not embeded in new version of Eclipse(Users have to intall csv plugin by themselves)，so users can't modify the `CVS Console Font` in the `ColorsAndFontsPreferencePage` by default.

So, I suggest you using `IDebugUIConstants.PREF_CONSOLE_FONT` instead of `"pref_console_font"`, the `IDebugUIConstants.PREF_CONSOLE_FONT` is `Debug/Console Font` in the `ColorsAndFontsPreferencePage`.

Answer (score 1):

Hum, I think you can go in the preferences, then General > Appearance > Color and Fonts.

[image]

Comment: I know this. This is not my question. I'm asking how I can ACCESS the font, not change it.

Comment: I don't think the font `Consolas` is the same as the font `Times new Roman`

Comment: Then Font("Consolas")